# Surjectivity of $f(x) = x^2$ for range of real numbers.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Is $f(x) = x^2$ surjective? given that $x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}$

My solution:

$x^2 = y$

$x = \pm \sqrt{y}$

For the negative values in codomain, sqrt of them will give complex numbers.

Hence, range $\neq$ elements in codomain,

hence not surjective.

(sorry for the disgusting symbols)

Comment: Yes of course! You are right!

Comment: Please [read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And if you're talking about $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=x^2$, then clearly $f$ will *not* be surjective. No negative number in $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped to, and that's all you really need to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not surjective, note that if you are considering $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then any $-a\in \mathbb{R}$ needs a pre-image. This means $f^{-1}(\{-a\})\in \mathbb{R}$, but $x^2$ only maps to positive numbers, so all the negative numbers are "missed", so it cannot be surjective.

Comment: What do you mean by $-a$? Just use $-1$ instead.